# How can I resize images in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL library but I am getting many errors.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img_size = 64
data_path='C:/Users/Cadet/Downloads/Data/Data/'
labels = listdir(data_path)
x_cat=[];
cat_imgpath = listdir(data_path+'/'+labels[0])

for img in cat_imgpath:
 cat_img = io.imread(data_path+'/'+labels[0]+'/'+img)
 x_cat.append(resize(cat_img, (img_size, img_size), PIL.Image.BICUBIC))
```

I have also changed the last line to:

```
 x_cat.append(np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(cat_img).resize(64, 64 , resample = PIL.Image.BICUBIC)))
```

and

```
 x_cat.append.cat_img.resize((img_size, img_size), PIL.Image.BICUBIC))
```

And it didn't work.

That's the error that I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-fe907917e104> in <module>
      4 for img in cat_imgpath:
      5  cat_img = io.imread(data_path+'/'+labels[0]+'/'+img)
----> 6  x_cat.append(resize(cat_img, (img_size, img_size), PIL.Image.BICUBIC))
      7 
      8 

NameError: name 'resize' is not defined
```

I am willing to use other libraries and modules. Initially, I tried to use `scipy.misc` and import `imresize` but it looks like this package has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you appended just the resize function without applying it to an Image variable:

```
 x_cat.append(resize(cat_img, (img_size, img_size), PIL.Image.BICUBIC))
```

Instead of:

```
x_cat.append(cat_img.resize((img_size,img_size)))
```

Here is a simple use case of resize() method of PIL.Image which works for me.
Note that the param of resize() is a tuple.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.load()
new_size = (100, 110)
smaller_img = img.resize(new_size)
```